# How to correctly use aspect ratio in swift xcode storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I've been scratching my head about this all day. I am try to have the iphone 6s reflect what the iphone 12 is showing. I'm not good at autolayout but I'd just like an idea or a point in the right direction so I can make it look like its counterpart. All help is appreciated.

[image]

(P.S I'm using storyboard and have never tried to do it programmatically.)

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What UI elements are those 6 ?

Comment: I think it is not about autolayout. You can arrange this view with UICollectionView and sets its spacing and cell size

Comment: First, are you going to have ***exactly*** six "tiles"? Or will you have a varying number? If varying, you probably want to use a collection view and allow scrolling when there are too many to fit. If you're going to always have six, then you need to decide how you *want* it to look on smaller screens / devices... such as this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOszJ.png

Comment: @DonMag  I do need exactly six, when I run it on the iphone 6 screen it just looks mushed up. How could I use it whereby the iiphone 6s reflects the iphone 12. Is it aspect ratio I should use?

Comment: @Kamanda - do you want it to look like the image I posted?

Comment: @DonMag yes please, i've been working on this and I haven't got it to look like the image you presented. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea...

- use a Vertical Stack View holding 3 "rows" of Horizontal Stack Views
- each Horizontal stack view holds two "tile" `UIView`s
- set `Alignment: Fill`, `Distribution: Fill Equally` and `Spacing: 0` on all the stack views
- give the first view (in this image, the red view) an Aspect Ratio constraint ... from your image, it looks like you want `3:2.5`
- embed the stack view in a "container" `UIView` - I called it `GridView`
- constrain the stack view `>= 12` on all 4 sides
- **also** constrain the stack view `= 12` on all 4 sides, but give those constraints `Priority: High (750)` ... this will cause auto-layout to "pull" the stack view to the edges, but allow it to be narrower if needed
- then we **also** give the stack view Center Vertical and Horizontal constraints
- constrain GridView to Zero Leading, Trailing and Bottom

That will give you 6 tiles that will maintain their aspect-ratios based on device size, and it will center the vertical stack view if needed:

[image]

The next step would be to embed a "rounded corner bordered" view in each "tile" view, constraining it at 8-pts on all 4 sides (less or more to get your desired "spacing"):

[image]

Here's the result on an iPhone 12 and iPhone 6s:

[image]

As you can see, there is **less** vertical space between the labels and the banner and grid views, and there is slightly more **horizontal** space on the sides of the stack view.

Here's a link to the Storyboard source and class files I used for this, so you can try it out and inspect the elements. I used just enough to demonstrate. You would probably want to make a custom "tile" view class that would contain the rounded corner bordered view and label:

https://gist.github.com/DonMag/8a0b2d85bbbb4262e43d73e745826ee5

Comment: Thank you so much. Perfectly explained and i've learnt something great!. Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

It's all the game of constraints if you want to handle this using story board.

There are multiple ways to achieve this UI. Either you can use UICollectionView and use UICollectionViewCells to show 2 cells in each column to manage the data or you can use UIStackView to manage your UI easily.

If you want square shapes, then you must use UIScrollView as the UI can exceed Screen Height. If not, just put your view in UIStackView and let it handle some of your UI constraints itself.