# How to implement Auto Layout to fit a StackView with UIButtons inside UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, uikit, xib

I create a custom Numpad keyboard through xib and stuck on its proper layout.

`NumpadView` has 4 rows in total: 3 rows with 5 buttons and 1 last row with 4 buttons.

Here is how it looks in a `xib` now:

[image]

I want to make all the `UIButtons` round with `Aspect Ratio` 1:1 and for `NumpadView` to be able to fit all buttons properly regardless of the `height` it can be initialized with.

I found a great answer with a similar problem on Stack Overflow: [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703605/how-to-correctly-use-aspect-ratio-in-swift-xcode-storyboard) and followed it. On the upper screenshot you can see constraints I made based on its best answer.

**The problem I have:**

`UIButtons` don't change the size and fit the `NumpadView` frame (by height):

[image]

And If I will add a top constraint to a `GridView` then `Aspect Ratio` on `UIButtons` doesn't work:

[image]

I need the `NumpadView` to be able to fit all `UIButtons` inside and the buttons should stay round regardless of `NumpadView` height. How can I modify the `Auto Layout` to be able to solve this task?

Test project to play with: [Github](https://github.com/artexhibit/CustomNumpad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your height, its with your width.
It doesn't work because your main UIStackView (vertical) has leading and trailing constraint with constant of 10 it overrides the ratio you set and causes the stretch of the buttons.

The solution is to add a center constraint between that UIStackView and its superview, and change its leading, trailing constraint to `greater or equal`.
That will provide the solution you need.

Also, I noticed that you set the button cornerRadius on setup(), Moving it to `override func layoutSubviews()` will fix another issues you may encounter.

[image]

[image: Don't forget to set the aspect ratio of your buttons]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the kind answer. I moved setup to layoutSubviews(), thank you! If I centre the main Stack View to its Superview, then the buttons appear round, but then you can see it's a lot of space from left and right. How can I stretch them to fit that sides? Screenshot: https://share.cleanshot.com/qrqftt

Comment: You can increase the spacing between them on the horizontal UIStackViews. Also you can update the horizontal UIStackView distribution to equal spacing. But from my sight you are limited because you reached to the top and the bottom of the entire UIView. If you liked my answer please make a vote :).

Comment: Tal, thank you very much. I will vote for your answer for sure! Please take a look at the last detail: equal spacing made a trick, but not for the last horizontal SW with = sign. It has fill distribution since I need = sign to take all width+spacing of upper yellow buttons. How can I fix that? Here is xib code for you for faster look: https://gist.github.com/artexhibit/735ba2ff0593826a1e4114f0bb81f7b8

Comment: You are limited here, please describe what behavior you want, if you want 1:1 aspect ratio, consider changing the VisualEffectView height.

Comment: Voted as promised :) Yes, wanted 1:1 aspect ratio, there is a thing that I wanted to limit the view's hight to 1/3 of device screen, that is why I though there is a chance to set up the numpad to stretch across available device width and 1/3 height and leave all buttons round